# What should I learn next? After HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, web

My dream is to learn how to build a site like [funcage.com](http://funcage.com) - it's a funny picture site, but I want options for users to register and upload their own pictures, vote for those picture, comment on them etc.

So, anyway I have spent over a year learning and experimenting with HTML & CSS went through the nettuts HTML & CSS course I have built a few small project websites which I am happy with and I want to learn how to get close to my dream.

What is the next step? I have looked into it and if you know what I should learn next, give me some good resources please :)

Comment: You need to learn JavaScript and a serverside language (PHP, Python, .NET, Node.JS, etc.).

Comment: How about Shakespeare?

Comment: Blender or just Javascript, which you can use as a server-side language too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next logical step (in my opinion) is [PHP](http://php.net/).

Most modern websites, such as picture hosting sites, are built on either [PHP](http://php.net/) or [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/). This is what gives it the power to "dynamically" change the content you see, depending on the user's interactions.

Another thing you'd need is a database. [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) is a common free one that a lot of people like (it's now owned by Oracle).

If you're using a Windows PC, you can get started by downloading [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), which is a simple installer to get you started with PHP and MySQL. It also contains the popular webserver [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/).

I also agree with other people's answers about [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) - it's an extremely widely used thing nowadays... but I think as a starter, you should look at some PHP tutorials.

Apache, PHP, and MySQL are all open-source software. You'd be surprised how quickly you'd get your picture site going! Small tutorials on how to connect to a database etc, all quickly progress into something bigger.

The PHP [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is a great place to look for how to a use a specific function, and as always, [Google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=connect%20to%20mysql%20database%20php&aq=f&oq=connect%20to%20mysql%20database%20php&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.8638&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)!

Comment: There are lots of languages and frameworks used for web development that are neither PHP nor ASP.NET (and I'd pick quite a few of them before I'd choose either of those two).

Comment: Yeah I read up on that too! But I have difficulty finding a great place to learn it like in youtube or nettuts where did you learn it from

Comment: and if you want to play with PHP and MySQL on a mac you can download MAMP its also free and awesome :-)

Comment: Mac goes hand in hand with Ruby (on Rails). Which is also my framework of choice and I love it, I would never go back to PHP.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit dated by suggesting PHP (I don't believe so), but it's certainly an easy place for a beginner to start learning the craft. I wouldn't look at YouTube or anywhere like that, I'd just get Xampp installed and get cracking with Notepad++ or Dreamweaver. Google as you go!! e.g. "Connect to database PHP", or "User input PHP", etc etc.

Comment: +1 I am a Java guy, but with PHP you get much easier started. You can right start of making your first dynamic webpage without configuring and reading for hours. This is good for motivation, less frustrating and therefore good for fast learning. No problem to switch later to something else but for the beginning PHP is really good imho. Especially when he's completely learning on his own without a teacher.

Comment: This is true but on the other hand you get sucked into plain bad programming practices. It's not that PHP is bad as a language but the majority of PHP code and tutorials on the web are.

Comment: @mrbrdo You're completely right! I think that's part and parcel of learning to code though...

Comment: Well it's the only way I know too, but I started with PHP. Can't help but think I could've saved myself some time if I started with something else. When I started using proper frameworks a whole new world opened to me, I suddenly realized just how bad my code was.

Comment: @mrbrdo Don't know if we are the only ones, but I think every programmer has this feeling. It's independent from the fact what language you've learned first. Every programmer I know had written really "bad code" in his first years. Even today I like to read code from other "famous" developers and learn from them - it's just that the learning curve is slowing down over time.

Comment: Well sure you can't start with great code, what I meant is that PHP is bad influence (the tutorials). So you need to break from that procedural style code at some point to get better, if you stay there you might think you're writing good code but you're probably not. Even doing OOP from the start would probably have a very positive influence, but if you start with PHP you get sucked into the old procedural-style programming sooner or later. If nothing else you have to use a lot of procedural code (such as the majority of PHP's stdlib).

Comment: @mrbrdo PHP is OOP too... *hides in corner*

Comment: I know it is, but the stdlib isn't, and most tutorials for PHP don't do OOP. Like I said before, PHP is not a bad language, the other things are the problem.

Answer (score 3):

HTML and CSS is just for structure and presentation. You need to have some sort of serverside language that dynamically generates the HTML and stores data in a database.

There are *tons* of serverside languages available, but the most common are:

- Python
- Ruby
- PHP
- Node.JS
- ASP.NET

Along with a serverside language, you'll benefit quite a bit from [learning JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide). I'd start with JavaScript.

Comment: With how much javascript today's websites usually have, this is a good answer. Although might also use Coffeescript instead of Javascript but both are a good choice to start with.

Comment: @mrbrdo: CS is like a completely different language (at least to me). I wouldn't recommend starting with it.

Comment: Different compared to what? The person asking the question only has experience with HTML and CSS! To him Javascript is just as different from HTML as Coffeescript is. And from Coffeescript it's quite easy to transition into Ruby or Python since they both have similar syntax.

Comment: @mrbrdo: I haven't seen many exclusively CoffeeScript tutorials.

Comment: Well I can't argue with that, Coffee is fairly new. But it is a nice language (much nicer than JS in my opinion). Also for beginners the problem with JS is the object model and the tendency to not do object-orientated things. But in general I agree, JS is still a good choice to start with.

Comment: @mrbrdo: I like the syntax of plain JavaScript. But that's probably because that's all I use.

Comment: Trust me, it is :) You need a few days to get the hang of Coffee but after that you can't ever go back.

Answer (score 1):

logical next step would be javascript

[Mozilla  developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide)

**Additional Note**

Use node.js as the backend, and you only need to learn one more language - Javascript - client side and server side

Comment: What would that help me in the making of a website like funcage? Would it be where you register or something?

Comment: W3Schools has no affiliation with the W3C and they have crappy content. Don't link to them. Use the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @user1848831 You can't register/login etc without a server-side language like PHP, ASP, etc. JavaScript is a [sic] "necessary" language, but it's client-side.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Node.js is a serverside JavaScript implementation.

Comment: @Blender Nice, I'd heard about Node.js, but I've never looked into it. Sadly, I don't get much time to learn too many new languages! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score -1):

If you are not focusing on web. Python is something you can consider.

Comment: Python has a ton of good web frameworks.

Comment: -1 because you said "if you are not focusing on web". Python is great for web.